# Find an specific item in the master list of an split app by using oModel.createKey

Tags: odata, sapui5, master-detail

I'm using a split app layout for editing and creating new employees. Therefore I do have a button "Add employee". After submitChanges is done, I want to find this new employee in the master list and select it.

I am using an event-bus for the communication between detail-controller and master-controller.

```
fnAfterSubmitChangesSuccess: function(sChanel, sEvent, oData) {        
   var oResponseData = oData.__batchResponses[0].__changeResponses[0].data;
   var sBindingPath = oModel.createKey("/EmployeeSet", {Begda: oData.Begda, Endda: oData.Endda, Pernr: oData.Pernr}).replace(/:\s*/g, "%3A");    
},
```

Is there a way to find the index of a specific listitem by the using binding-path. Or is there another way to solve this problem, instead of looping over the whole list a do a comparison?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid the only way to find the index of a specific listItems by binding-path is to walk through the collection of list items. So, I'm afraid that a very plain and short answer would be "No".

It's quite easy though, code is not that lengthy, and it also shouldn't cost to much performance if you're not talking about humongous lists. You will have to walk through the list of items though. Once you have found the item with a binding to the context path you're looking for, you can select it using `setSelectedItem`, like so:

```
var list = this.getView().byId("list");
jQuery.each(list.getList(), function(idx, item) {
    if (items.getBindingContext().getPath = sBindingPath) {
        list.setSelectedItem(item);
    }
});
```

Note: Do keep in mind that if you're working with OData services and are working with a so-called 'growing list', the entry you're looking for may not necessarily be in the list.

Apologies, wish I could give you a more pleasant answer.

Comment: I'll go with you "No" :)